# Database Migration from Oracle to Aurora Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, amazon-aurora

I am trying to migrate data from Oracle to Postgres. I have installed the Schema Conversion Tool and conversion is successful after running test.  But anytime I choose the the schema that I want to analyze, it always says report can't be created for the node. Any help please?

I am expecting to generate the assessment report for the sourceDB